# DateTime value not assigned to DateTimePicker when DateTimePicker is not checked (at start time)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

In a WinForms application, I have a `DateTimePicker`

Properties from `...Designer.cs`

```
        this.dateTimePicker.AllowDrop = true;
        this.dateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
        this.dateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        this.dateTimePicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(251, 12);
        this.dateTimePicker.Name = "DateTimePicker";
        this.dateTimePicker.ShowCheckBox = true;
        this.dateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
        this.dateTimePicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 28);
        this.dateTimePicker.TabIndex = 1;
```

Whenever its value changed, I save what I need to the application settings( I did similar thing for many other "field" and this is the first one where I encounter a problem:

```
... this.Settings = [MyApplication].Properties.Settigns.Default.

private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time = this.dateTimePicker.Value;
    this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Checked = this.dateTimePicker.Checked;
    this.Settings.Save();
}
```

When the application is launch, actually, in the main form's constructor, I restore the saved values as follows, (note that the ValueChange event is only bound to the control after the assignation of initial values):

```
        this.dateTimePicker_Time.Checked = this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Checked;
        if (this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time != null)
        {
            this.dateTimePicker.Value = this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time;
        }

        this.dateTimePicker.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dateTimePicker_ValueChanged);
```

**Problem**
If the `DateTimePicker` is checked, `DateTime` value is assigned as expected.
But if the `DateTimePicker` is not checked, `DateTime` value is not assign, it seem that `DateTime.Now` is assigned instead.

Hence, I also tried the following code, but the result is the same:

```
        this.dateTimePicker_Time.Checked = this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Checked;
        if (this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time != null)
        {
            bool dateTimePicker_Checked = this.dateTimePicker.Checked;
            this.dateTimePicker.Checked = true;
            this.dateTimePicker.Value = this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time;
            this.dateTimePicker.Checked = dateTimePicker_Checked ;
        }

        this.dateTimePicker.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dateTimePicker_ValueChanged);
```

**Edit**
I have tried to DataBind the DateTimePicker propeties to the applications settings, but the result is the same as doing things "manually" as here above.

Answer (score 2):

Some settings for controls aren't ready yet when you are in the constructor.  You found one of those settings.

Try moving your restore code to the form's OnLoad override.  Please note that changing the Value property of the DateTimePicker will set the Checked property to true, so you need to set the Checked property *after* you set the Value property:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnLoad(e);
  if (this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time != null) {
    this.dateTimePicker2.Value = this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time;
  }
  this.dateTimePicker2.Checked = this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Checked;
}
```

Also, it would make more sense to just save the settings once in the OnFormClosing override:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Time = dateTimePicker2.Value;
  this.Settings.dateTimePicker_Checked = dateTimePicker2.Checked;
  this.Settings.Save();
  base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: The you, I'll try to test thig this week-end. Though I have already tried to put the code in the Form_Load method which is bound to Load event so I expect that OnLoad will give the same result.

Comment: @TTT I duplicated your issue.  Keep in mind, the code you posted would never save Checked = false, since unchecking that box does not trigger the ValueChanged event.